# ",@" in lisp macro functions

Tags: macros, common-lisp, evaluation

From http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/practical-a-simple-database.html :

> The ,@ "splices" the value of the following expression--which must
>   evaluate to a list--into the enclosing list. You can see the
>   difference between , and ,@ in the following two expressions:

```
`(and ,(list 1 2 3))   ==> (AND (1 2 3)) 

`(and ,@(list 1 2 3))  ==> (AND 1 2 3)
```

Even with the example, I can't gather what the `,@` does. Could someone explicitly mention the steps in the second example? (Yes, lisp beginner here)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are not understanding? You can see that in one case, you still have parens, and in the other case you don't. You can think of `,@` as just running one extra step at the end, where it removes the parens from lists. Do you already understand what `\`` and `,` do?

Comment: is it simply that  `@` removes the list? I think I understand what backquote and `,` do. Backquote = will not be evaluated. Comma = will be evaluated. Right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct about backtick and comma. Strictly speaking I think that what `,@` actually does is add `. ,`. You can see this if you do `,@` on something that is not a list. The thing is that the `.` tells lisp to explicitly put something in the cons cell. However, putting a list in the cons cell simply extends the current list. Basically, it "de-nests" the list. Instead of having a list with AND as the first element and the second element is a nested list 1 2 3, you end up with a single list because 1 2 3 has been appended to the one element list containing AND.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a slightly modified version of your example:

```
`(foo bar ,(list 1 2 3) baz)   ==> (foo bar (1 2 3) baz) 

`(foo bar ,@(list 1 2 3) baz)  ==> (foo bar  1 2 3  baz)
```

In the first expression the list `(1 2 3)` is inserted as an element in the resulting list. In the second expression the elements of the list `(1 2 3)` becomes elements in the resulting list. The lists are "spliced".

Answer (score 2):

Note that the backquote feature is independent of *macros*. It's a general mechanism to construct lists from *templates*. Since Lisp source code is based on lists, it's sometimes also useful to construct Lisp source code from source code templates.

```
CL-USER 86 > `(one   pi ,(* 1 pi)
               two   pi ,(* 2 pi)    
               three pi ,(* 3 pi))
(ONE PI 3.141592653589793D0
 TWO PI 6.283185307179586D0
 THREE PI 9.42477796076938D0)

CL-USER 87 > `((one   pi ,(* 1 pi))
               (two   pi ,(* 2 pi))
               (three pi ,(* 3 pi)))
((ONE PI 3.141592653589793D0)
 (TWO PI 6.283185307179586D0)
 (THREE PI 9.42477796076938D0))


CL-USER 90 > `(((one pi) (two pi) (three pi))
               ,(loop for i from 1 upto 3 collect (list (* pi i))))
(((ONE PI) (TWO PI) (THREE PI))
 ((3.141592653589793D0) (6.283185307179586D0) (9.42477796076938D0)))
```

Here an example with `,@`, where the result list is spliced in. The result list disappears and its elements become members of the resulting list.

```
CL-USER 91 > `(((one pi) (two pi) (three pi))
               ,@(loop for i from 1 upto 3 collect (list (* pi i))))
(((ONE PI) (TWO PI) (THREE PI))
  (3.141592653589793D0) (6.283185307179586D0) (9.42477796076938D0))
```